# How to pass useState amoung the components in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, use-state, prop

I have a register page and Modal component. In register has a `useState` for visibility of the Modal. I'm passing it as a prop to Modal. When the modal is closed how to change the `useState` value in the register page.

Register page:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
  CCard,
  CButton,
  CCardBody,
  CCardHeader,
  CCol,
  CForm,
  CFormInput,
  CFormLabel,
  CSpinner,
  CRow,
} from '@coreui/react'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'
import { cilSend } from '@coreui/icons'
import Alert from 'src/components/Alert'
import Modal from 'src/components/Modal'

const FormControl = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false)
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  const handleAddMember = async () => {
    try {
      const data = { email, name }

      const _data = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/member/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      })

      if (_data.status === 201) {
        setVisible(true)
        setDisabled(false)
      } else if (_data.status === 422) {
        setDisabled(false)
      } else {
        setDisabled(false)
        throw new Error()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setDisabled(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <CRow>
      <Modal visible={visible} message="Member added to your community successfully!" />
      <CCol xs={6}>
        <CCard className="mb-4">
          <CCardHeader>
            <strong>Add New Member</strong>
          </CCardHeader>
          <CCardBody>
            <p className="text-medium-emphasis small">
              Fill in the email address field and name field to add a new member to your community.
            </p>
            <CForm>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <CFormLabel>Email address:</CFormLabel>
                <CFormInput
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="name@example.com"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setEmail(e.target.value)
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              
              <div className="mb-3">
                <CFormLabel>Name:</CFormLabel>
                <CFormInput
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Perera's Home"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setName(e.target.value)
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              
              <div className="mb-3">
                <CButton color="primary" disabled={disabled} onClick={() => handleAddMember()}>
                  {disabled ? (
                    <CSpinner component="span" className="me-2" size="sm" aria-hidden="true" />
                  ) : (
                    <CIcon icon={cilSend} className="me-2" />
                  )}
                  Submit
                </CButton>
              </div>
            </CForm>
          </CCardBody>
        </CCard>
      </CCol>
    </CRow>
  )
}

export default FormControl
```

Modal component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { CButton, CModal, CModalBody, CModalFooter, CModalHeader, CModalTitle } from '@coreui/react'

const Modal = (props) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(props.visible)

  return (
    <CModal alignment="center" visible={visible} onClose={() => setVisible(false)}>
      <CModalHeader>
        <CModalTitle>Success!</CModalTitle>
      </CModalHeader>
      <CModalBody>{props.message}</CModalBody>
      <CModalFooter>
        <CButton color="primary" onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>
          Close
        </CButton>
      </CModalFooter>
    </CModal>
  )
}

Modal.propTypes = {
  visible: PropTypes.bool,
  message: PropTypes.string,
}

export default React.memo(Modal)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have just *one* `visible` state member, either in the parent component or in the child (`Modal`), rather than having it in both places.

If you put it in the parent, you can pass it to the child just like any other prop:

```
return <Modal visible={visible} setVisible={setVisible}>{/*...*/}</Modal>
```

`Modal`'s code can then call `props.setVisible` with the appropriate flag.

If you *only* want `Modal` to be able to hide itself (not show itself), you might instead pass a wrapper function that calls `setVisible(false)`:

```
const hide = useCallback(() => setVisible(false), [setVisible]);
//                Optional, see below −−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^
// ...
return <Modal visible={visible} hide={hide}>{/*...*/}</Modal>
```

...and then `Modal`'s code calls `hide()` to hide the modal.

*(Making `setVisible` a dependency in the `useCallback` call is optional; state setter functions are* stable*; they don't change during the lifetime of the component. Some linters aren't quite smart enough to realize that and may nag you if you don't include it, but most are smarter than that.)*

Here's a highly simplified example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    return <div>
        <input type="button" value="Open" disabled={visible} onClick={() => setVisible(true)} />
        <Modal visible={visible} setVisible={setVisible} />
    </div>;
};

const Modal = (props) => {
    if (!props.visible) {
        return null;
    }
    return <div className="modal">
        <div>This is the modal</div>
        <input type="button" value="Close" onClick={() => props.setVisible(false)} />
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.modal {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Or with destructuring (I generally use destructuring with props, but it didn't look like you were):

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    return <div>
        <input type="button" value="Open" disabled={visible} onClick={() => setVisible(true)} />
        <Modal visible={visible} setVisible={setVisible} />
    </div>;
};

const Modal = ({visible, setVisible}) => {
    if (!visible) {
        return null;
    }
    return <div className="modal">
        <div>This is the modal</div>
        <input type="button" value="Close" onClick={() => setVisible(false)} />
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.modal {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: @NiPoo - I don't use PropType (I use TypeScript). [Looking at the lib](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types), it seems like it would be really generic, `PropTypes.func`. In TypeScript it would be much more specific, `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>`.

Comment: I have used `<CButton onClick={() => props.setVisible(false)} />` but generating an error by saying `TypeError: props.setVisible is not a function`.

Comment: @NiPoo - That part is okay, so the problem would be in how you're passing `setVisible` to `Modal`. If you do it as I've shown above, that should work.

Comment: @NiPoo - I've added a simplified example to the answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry. There had just a capital/simple letter error. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: @NiPoo - No worries! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the setVisible as well in the modal component and then use the same setState on both component

```
 <Modal visible={visible} setVisible={setVisible} message="Member added to your community successfully!" />
```

use this like

```
props.visible
props.setVisible
```

Comment: try PropTypes.func hope it will work fine @NiPoo

Comment: I have used `<CButton onClick={() => props.setVisible(false)} />` but generating an error by saying `TypeError: props.setVisible is not a function`.

Comment: you need to pass setVisible in a Modal component to work 
`setVisible={setVisible} `
it is not getting setVisible